# SQL Inner join in a nested select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to do an inner join in a nested select statement. Basically, There are first and last reason IDs that produce a certain number (EX: 200). In another table, there are definitions for the IDs. I'm trying to pull the Last ID, along with the corresponding comment for whatever is pulled (EX: 200 - Patient Cancelled), then the first ID and the comment for whatever ID it is.

This is what I have so far:

```
Select BUSN_ID
    AREA_NAME
    DATE
    AREA_STATUS
(Select B.REASON_ID
      A.LAST_REASON_ID
      FROM BUSN_INFO A, BUSN_REASONS B
    WHERE A.LAST_REASON _ID=B.REASON_ID,
    (Select B.REASON_ID
          A. FIRST_REASON_ID
        FROM BUSN_INFO A, BUSN_REASONS B
        WHERE A_FIRST_REASON_ID = B.REASON_ID)
FROM BUSN_INFO
```

I believe an inner join is best, but I'm stuck on how it would actually work.

Required result would look like (this is example dummy data):

```
First ID -- Busn Reason --       Last ID -- Busn Reason
1           Patient Sick          2          Patient Cancelled
2           Patient Cancelled     2          Patient Cancelled
3           Patient No Show       1          Patient Sick
```

Justin_Cave's SECOND example is the way I used to solve this problem.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your example. Show us your complete stored procedure

Comment: We're going to need table structure, example data and required result.  I don't see any PLSQL, so I removed that tag from your question.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I included the SQL. Working in the PLSQL environment though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use inline select statements, your inline `select` has to select a single column and should just join back to the table that is the basis of your query.  In the query you posted, you're selecting the same numeric identifier multiple times.  My guess is that you really want to query a string column from the lookup table-- I'll assume that the column is called `reason_description`

```
Select BUSN_ID,
       AREA_NAME,
       DATE,
       AREA_STATUS,
       a.last_reason_id,
       (Select B.REASON_description
          FROM BUSN_REASONS B
         WHERE A.LAST_REASON_ID=B.REASON_ID), 
       a.first_reason_id,
       (Select B.REASON_description
          FROM BUSN_REASONS B
         WHERE A.FIRST_REASON_ID = B.REASON_ID)
FROM BUSN_INFO A
```

More conventionally, though, you'd just join to the `busn_reasons` table twice

```
SELECT i.busn_id,
       i.area_name,
       i.date,
       i.area_status,
       i.last_reason_id,
       last_reason.reason_description,
       i.first_reason_id,
       first_reason.reason_description
  FROM busn_info i
       JOIN busn_reason first_reason
         ON( i.first_reason_id = first_reason.reason_id )
       JOIN busn_reason last_reason
         ON( i.last_reason_id = last_reason.reason_id )
```

Comment: Tried it the first way and it wouldn't work. The second way did - thank you so much. I did forget the reason description.

Comment: @ITNovice15 - Can you explain "wouldn't work"?  The first approach and the second approach should return an identical data set assuming that `reason_id` is unique in `busn_reasons` and ignoring `null` values.

Comment: I get ORA-01427; single-row subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: That implies that `reason_id` is not unique in `busn_reasons`.  That likely means that the second query is returning additional rows that you don't really want.

Comment: Any idea on a quick fix? I've set up two different aliases for the busn_reasons, and set that in front of reason_id to try to make them unique

Comment: I just figured it out, Justin! Inside each inline statement I set the business ideas to each other for each alias I created. That solved the duplicate data problem. Thanks again.